# \cdot not working in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

If I try to use `\cdot` in my .tex document (moderncv) then I'm getting error like this:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
(inserted text)
                $
here_it_gives_line_number_and_hint
```

This line have this structure:

`\tlcventry[orange]{year}{0}{DESC_1}{\href{http://DESC_1}{DESC_1} \cdot \href{http://DESC_1}{DESC_1}}{DESC_1}{ \scriptsize{\underline{\textbf{DESC_1}}} }{DESC_COMMENT}`

When I remove `\cdot` from it, then my document compiles sucessfully.

Comment: as the error message says, `\cdot` is a math command, you have to use it in math mode: `$\cdot$`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\cdot` works only in mathmode so type `$\cdot$`. By the way the error message gave you the correct hint.

```
\tlcventry[orange]{year}{0}{DESC_1}{\href{http://DESC_1}{DESC_1}$\cdot$ \href{http://DESC_1}{DESC_1}}{DESC_1}{ \scriptsize{\underline{\textbf{DESC_1}}} }{DESC_COMMENT}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, `\cdot` only works in math mode, so you can write `$\cdot$`.

However, a more elegant solution in my opinion is to use `\textbullet`, which is the equivalent of `\cdot` but for text mode.

Comment: `\textbullet` isn't exactly the equivalent. It gives a different shape, especially in `moderncv`: for example, under the `banking` style, it's redefined to be a filled square.